# File upload not working, nothing gets uploaded

Tags: python, django, forms

Here's the model

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
```

The template

```
{% extends 'another-form.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_field form.files %}
    <button class="btn btn-success col">Upload</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Form class and view:

```
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView


class UploadDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), label='')


class UploadDocumentView(FormView):
    template_name = 'upload-document.html'
    form_class = UploadDocumentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('upload-document')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Document.objects.bulk_create([Document(file=f) for f in self.request.FILES])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

when the form is submitted, I get these responses:

```
[02/Jan/2023 14:43:13] "POST /upload-document/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Jan/2023 14:43:14] "GET /upload-document/ HTTP/1.1" 200 70636
[02/Jan/2023 14:43:17] "GET /upload-document/ HTTP/1.1" 200 70635
```

and nothing is uploaded to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` which is specified in `settings.py` and works for `models.ImageField`. I also tried

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

which is useless, just included for completeness, also:

```
class UploadDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    files = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), label=''
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're dealing with multiple files, so you should use **getlist** instead. eg:

```
Document.objects.bulk_create([Document(file=f) for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('files'])
```